# Separating as a client the server's transport and message signature certificates with WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, wcf-client

I am currently in the process of integrating a WCF client into a java web service. The server requires the client to authenticate via certificate using SSL and the message to be signed.

I have successfully sent the message to the server through SSL, Signed, etc. However, the server response message is also signed but with a different certificate than the one used to authenticate the server.

The WCF client doesn't like this behavior. It failed with the message: "The incoming message was signed with a token which was different from what used to encrypt the body. This was not expected." The problem is described [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.aspnet.webservices/browse_thread/thread/eb333ab64411a1a3/ff1525c817cd3e87?lnk=gst&q=Certificate%20issue%20with%20WCF%20client%20accessing%20webservice%20via%20broker#ff1525c817cd3e87) in detail.

Looking around on Google I found it is possible to decouple the clients transport certificate from the singing certificate by implementing ClientCredentials and other security related classes, and adding a new extension. You can read all the details about it [here](http://blogesh.wordpress.com/2009/10/08/separate-certificates-for-transport-and-message-security-in-wcf/). However I'm having some trouble figuring out where exactly do i have to extend to provide this same behavior for the server's certificate on client mode.

Any help on the subject or reference would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729856.aspx)

This shows you how to create an custom ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager that allows you to specify the various **message** signing and encryption certificates for requests and responses to and from the server.

I emphasise message because the problem as you describe it appears to me to be message security validation. The transport security is seaperate from the mechanism used to validate the message security, i.e. the message signature and message decryption.

Ignore the transport security as this is lower down in the WCF pipeline and appears to be working working correctly from your description. A seaperate concern is the message security. It appears that you need to be able to use a certificate for decrypting the response and a certificate for verifying the signature. The above article shows a example for enabling this type of certificate managment, it does detail how you could create behaviours and extensions to apply this to your client that is a seaperate concern. This depends on how you want to configure your proxies i.e. through code or through configuration.

The example [article](http://blogesh.wordpress.com/2009/10/08/separate-certificates-for-transport-and-message-security-in-wcf/) you linked too is not a complete implementation for what you require, it only provides for a certifiate for signing and a certificate for the transport client credentials.

You could create a hybrid ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager that provides the transport certificate and the signing and decryption, this should be clear enough from looking at the [SecurityTokenRequirement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.securitytokenrequirement.aspx) documentation